# Database project build errors in TFS with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a solution containing a web application and multiple database projects.  While using the old XAML definition, I can compile and generate the database deployment files in TFS.  With the new definition introduced in TFS 2015, I can only generate the web application deployment files.

Here are parts of the log -

```
2016-10-28T22:14:48.6892904Z Build started 10/28/2016 4:14:48 PM.
2016-10-28T22:14:48.8883071Z      1>Project "E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\Test.Client.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2016-10-28T22:14:48.8893071Z      1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2016-10-28T22:14:48.8903071Z          Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
2016-10-28T22:14:49.0633142Z ##[warning]E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB4046: Error reading project file "..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj": Could not find a part of the path 'E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj'.
2016-10-28T22:14:49.0643150Z      1>Project "E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\Test.Client.sln" (1) is building "E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2016-10-28T22:14:49.0693159Z      2>E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj.metaproj : warning MSB4046: Error reading project file "..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj": Could not find a part of the path 'E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj'.
2016-10-28T22:14:49.0823182Z      2>Done Building Project "E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj.metaproj" (default targets).
```

I could not find much information on the new build definition.  Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Could your share your vnext build definition? And how did you generate the database deployment files in vNext build?

Comment: Where is the vNext definition file located in server?  I generated the deployment files in vNext build using web access from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what is wrong with this.  Our database projects are in another folder.  We need to map the server path with the local path in the Build's repository.  After added this, the database project can be built.

Answer (score 0):

First double check the difference of your two definitions XAML and vNext.

And check the file path `E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj` on the build agent, if there are the corresponding file.

And try to build your database project directly instead of building the whole solution to see if there are some useful info for troubleshooting.

---

Update

> Tips:
>
> - **You can also build MSBuild project (.*proj) files.**
> - If you are building a customized MSBuild project file, we recommend    you use the MSBuild step instead of the Visual Studio Build step.
>
> Source Link: [Visual Studio Build](https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-tw/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build)

Comment: how to check the difference of XAML and vNext definitions.  I have XAML as xml file.  But vNext is created through web url in the server.  Where can I find the definition file in the server?

Comment: I checked E:\TFS\agent\_work\1\s\..\Databases\Test\Test.DB.Test.sqlproj.  There is not a file there.

Comment: Can we build database project directly?  vNext seems to take solution file while XAML can take project files.

Comment: You don't have to check the original file, just need to manually  check the settings between your XAML and Vnext build definition. Such as mappings , triggers, variables and so on. This is what I mean. Finally the issue seems related to the wrong mappings. Great, you have figured out the issue.

Comment: @Don vNext is also support to build project files just as XAML. You can also build MSBuild project (.*proj) files in VS build task. Details please see my update.